# nginx caching doesn't seem to be working with django

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django

I have a few django apps that I wanted to try caching with NGINX. I followed this guide. https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

I used the `include` directive to include a file with this line in the `http` block...

```
proxy_cache_path /usr/share/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my cache:10m max_size=2g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
```

I then went to the `sites-enabled` folder and added this to my server blocks, these are ssl blocks...

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate my/path/to/ssl;
    ssl_certificate_key my/path/to/ssl;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        alias /home/example/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        alias /home/example/example/static_dump;
    }

    location / {
        #Next two lines added while developing includes only ip's in the file
        include /etc/nginx/ip-allow.conf;
        deny all;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_pass http://app_server_example;
    }
```

I see when I check the path to the cache file that it has created a `./tmp` folder so I guess the permissions are correct, and when I restarted nginx with `nginx -s reload` and then later `service nginx restart` I never got any errors.

Why would there be no files showing up in these caching directories after there have been requests to my site?

Comment: As a follow up to the answer below do you see any of the `X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control` headers in your HTTP response from Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your Django application returns HTTP caching headers that do not allow caching of the pages.

If you want to ignore Django caching headers, then you can use this:

```
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
```